# How to read document binary data in langchain loader like json, excel, etc

Tags: python, loader, langchain

I want to pass a document byte data instead of passing file in langchain loader.

`loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path=path) data = loader.load_and_split()`

instated of a file in above code is it possible to pass binary data of that file?